# Angular how to check if string or array has value and effects of strict mode

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am writing some validations that will be applied to a string or an array. 
I will check whether the string or the array has a value.

The code is provided below.

Questions:

will strict mode be enabled for angular modules by default? 
based on my knowledge, the techniques to check whether the string or the array has a value differs if strict mode is enabled. So, considering the following use cases(mentioned as comments in the code), please provide me which is the correct solution:

Note: I am not using == or === operators while checking whether the string has a value and i am not sure whether my approach has any pitfalls.

```
private validate1(path:string):boolean
{
    // trim leading and trailing spaces (if any)
    path = path.trim();

    // 1. if path has a value && 2. if path starts with ":"
    if(path && path.startsWith(this.keySeparator)){
        // remove leading ":"
        path = path.substring(1);
    }
    // 1. if path has a value && 2. if path ends with ":"
    if(path && path.endsWith(this.keySeparator)){
        // remove trailing ":"
        path = path.slice(0, -1);
    }
    // does path still has a value
    // path is empty?
    if(!path){
        ///TODO throw an error
        return false;
    }

    const keys = path.split(this.keySeparator);
    // 1. did path.split succeed? && keys is not null or undefined 
    // 2. && keys is not empty
    if(!keys || keys.length <= 0){
        ///TODO throw an error
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Since both string and array implement a `.length`. Couldn't you just check that `path.length > 0` and your args would be `(path: string | Array)` ?

Comment: @James will `path.length` throw an error if path is null or undefined?

Comment: It will, just chuck a wee check `if(!path) { return false; }` Then the rest of your code can follow